# Is there a way to rename the last tmux window created?

Tags: tmux

I'm writing a script to leverage Tmux to run some commands; however, rather than having to constantly run `tmux list-windows`, get a count number, and assume the last window number, I'm wondering if there's a way to just simply rename the last window that was created so that I can reference that window from its name going forward.

Here's what I'm currently doing:

```
last_window=$(tmux list-windows | wc -l)
tmux rename-window -t session_name:$(last_window) new_window_name
```

but this seems a little messy. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I believe `tmux new-window` allows you to name the window *when you create it*. The relevant option is `-n window-name`.

Even if you need to rename it later (e.g. you retrieve the new name from a process in this very window somehow), you can create it with a name like `some_temporary_name`. Then you don't need to parse `tmux list-windows` to know the current name of the last window is `some_temporary_name`.